# Autofocus not working on Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup, magnific-popup

i'm using 'Magnific Popup' plugin for displaying a popup on my webpage. My need is to autofocus on a textarea when the popup is on. This enables user to type content there without using mouse.

I tried HTML5 autofocus tag

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textareaRemarks" autofocus>
</textarea>
```

and jQuery way

```
$('#textareaRemarks').focus();
```

Both found to be not working. Now user not only want to click but also arrange 'insertion point' to the initial position using arrow keys usually. How can I enable autofocus on Magnific Popup?

Code I'm using to enable Magnific Popup :

```
$('#textareaRemarks').focus();
$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#textareaRemarks',
        modal: true,
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have the Magnific Popup code?

Comment: Yes. It is available in https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/tree/master/dist

Comment: i mean the code you have in your website to load the popup and the content

Comment: Added that code too.

Comment: Try firing click event then the focus event.